# Replaying WebEx stream from %temp% files?

Tags: conversion, recording, webex

I am trying to replay a WebEx stream I have previously watched from temp files that were created when I originally watched the stream.

The original link to the stream no longer works and there was never a download link to save an `.arf` file.

It appears that when you stream a WebEx session from a link (and perhaps live, I have not tried) it creates a folder in your `%temp%` location with an 8 digit name (`52431122` for example). In that folder are a handful of files beginning with `wbxcbr_` and `wbxmcsr_` with `.std`, `.dat`, `.conf` and `.idx` extensions. Two of the `.dat` files are the largest by far and presumably contain the video and audio information.

I have tried renaming all of the files in the folder one at a time to `.avi`, `.mp4`, `.mp3` and `.arf` for playback in VLC and the WebEx Network Recording Player with no luck. I have also tried converting them to `.mp3` and `.mp4` with ffmpeg for playback with no luck.

I am happy to play back the stream using the WebEx software if there is a way to convert the files into a .arf file, but am willing to save/convert the files in to any playable format at this point.

Answer (score 7):

On [Rooted CON 2015](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeqrsQm33UBFHb50zorReHQ) Abel Valero [presented great video](https://youtu.be/cAmzxko81wE) with reversing WebEx data.

To simply get `*.arf` you can run [Abel rebuild tool from GitHub](https://github.com/skuater/rebuildwebex).

After that you can use WebEx Network Recording Player to convert `*.arf` file to appropriate video format (`.wmv`, `.swf` or `.mp4`)

---

**How to use steps**

If you already have WebEx temp files - just start from Step 5. If not - start from Step 1.

1. Open WebEx session in browser and follow the steps to install "WebEx Network Recording Player". Wait until video will be downloaded. There is a blue buffering indicator and it should be 100%
2. Download [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) - it's a program from [SysInternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) and install it
3. Run "Process Monitor" and adjust filters to show capturing from "Network Recording Player". I used following contains filter for that: `"ProcessName" contains "NRB"`
4. Look into process `nbrplay.exe` disk activity and obtain temporary folder path. Usually it's folder: `%windows%\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\<several digits>`
5. Copy contents of WebEx temp folder somewhere when full recording is downloaded (Step 2 - buffering indicator is 100%)
6. Download util from [here](https://github.com/skuater/rebuildwebex/raw/master/compilado/rebuild.zip) as a compiled executable (password is `webex`) or compile / adjust it to your needs
7. Run `rebuild.exe`, provide path from Step 5 into field `Ruta:` and press `Go` (it's a Spanish utility)
8. Wait for rebuild process - usually up to 10 sec. Util will save file with extension `*.arf` in the folder where utility itself is located
9. Open resulted `*.arf` file in the Network Recording Player: `File > Open`
10. Convert video to appropriate format for offline viewing `File > Convert Format` (usually `*.wmv` or `*.mp4`)

Comment: You really should include a quick summary of how to use the tool. Videos go down, and a consise, self contained answer is always so much better. The tool on github seems to lack any form of documentation

Comment: the tool worked for me. i then have an ARF file that can be converted further.

Comment: You can edit it into your answer

Comment: @journeyman-geek I agree - added "How to use" section

Comment: Is it normal that playing the ARF file doesn't have any audio?

Comment: rebuild.exe is pretty straightforward - run the tool - small winform pops; in "ruta" put path to the folder with webex temp files; click "go" - it will create rebuild.arf file;... "Acera de" button - "About", the other one "Salir"  - Exit.     about webex temp files - when you started to play webex from the web, pause recording and wait till buffer is completed, you can move play indicator, but do not close the window and do not let to play till the very end. - your webex temp files will be in %tmp%/[some 9 digit folder] - copy that folder to your safe location and convert from there.

Comment: There's an updated version with working audio. See the pull request on the github repo

Comment: The github repository is no longer online. Anyone has a working copy?

Answer (score -2):

Saturnix, try https://github.com/Piriaco/rebuildwebex this is another fork for the original one